# How to remove KDE Software Development Kit update notification in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, kde, notification, gnome-software

This update keeps popping up on notifications, but when I try to install it, it doesn't work. See a print of it:

[image]

I have not installed KDE-SDK or anything like it. I checked on synaptics.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `apt policy kde-dev-utils` show?

Comment: `N: impossible to find the package kde-dev-utils`

Comment: Intriguing, right?

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure stopped the notification, considering:

1) you don't have the kde sdk installed;
2) flathub is activated and properly running to other programs.

I've just deleted `/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Sdk` and `/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/remote/flathub/runtime/org.kde.Sdk`.

For some reason I don't know, maybe residues from another installation, there was some kde sdk files on those folders.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't worked well. It came back after a few days updating the system. Any new ideas?